# How can I create a new .NET Core 1.0 project after .NET Core 1.1 is installed

Tags: .net-core, sdk

After .NET Core SDK 1.1 is installed, how can I create a new .NET Core 1.0 project?

The `dotnet new` command does not seem to allow to choose the version.

Comment: Do you want .net core 1.0 or are you specifically looking to use project.json (e.g. old version of tooling/SDK)

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag for the `dotnet new` command to specify which frameworks to target

`dotnet new -f |--framework`

- Specifies which framework to target.
  Values: netcoreapp1.0 or netcoreapp1.1

(Default: netcoreapp1.0)

Here is the cli documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new